# ProgressBar Woes. Getting UI thread to update while reading database

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I'm having trouble getting a progress bar to update. I'd be okay just with a moving marquee bar. Basically, I'm reading a database routine in a SqliteReader.vb class. I'm new to visual basic, and I'm sure I need to use the worker_DoWork routine, but I'm not sure how to expose my variables coming from Form1: graphData, graphComputations, m_debug to the worker_DoWork sub. How is this usually done?

```
Public Class SqliteReader
   Public Sub ReadDataBase
     End Sub
End Class
```

This is updating a graph (zedgraph element) on the main form, Form1.vb. I call the progressbar from the main form like this:

```
    ProgressBar.Initialize(channelArray, computationArray, m_debug)
```

ProgressBar.vb below:

```
Partial Public Class ProgressBar
    Dim DataAcquisition As New SqliteReader
    Dim WithEvents worker As New BackgroundWorker

Public Sub Initialize(ByRef graphData As Channels(), ByRef graphComputations As Computations(), ByVal m_debug As Integer)
    DataAcquisition = SqliteReader.GetInstance()
    Me.Show()
    Me.Update()
    Dim Update_Thread As Thread(AddressOf Update_ThreadExecute)

    Update_Thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal
    Update_Thread.Start()
    DataAcquisition.ParseEntireDatabase(graphData, graphComputations, m_debug)
    Me.Close()
End Sub


Private Sub ProgressBarStart(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      DataAcquisition = SqliteReader.GetInstance()
      progress.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
      worker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
      worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
      worker.RunWorkerAsync()
  End Sub

  Private Sub worker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles worker.DoWork
         Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
         DataAcquisition = SqliteReader.GetInstance()
         ' I probably need 
         ' DataAcquisition.ParseEntireDatabase(graphData, graphComputations, m_debug)
         ' here... but how do I expose graphdata, graphcomputations and m_debug to this sub?
         End Sub

  Private Sub worker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles worker.ProgressChanged
      dataProgress = CInt(((DataAcquisition.currentRow + 1) / DataAcquisition.totalRows) * 100)
      progress.Value = dataProgress
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RunWorkerAsync has a second version that takes a parameter.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f00zz5b2.aspx) You can use that to pass any values (or references) your worker needs.

That said, you shouldn't be updating form elements from inside the worker. Your worker should fire the ProgressChanged event when you want the UI to update, and you handle it there. [That one also has a version that can send a value back.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) (Or many values if you send back an array, list, or custom class.)

The last step in this is that you need to actually fire ProgressChanged. `DataAcquisition.ParseEntireDatabase` may not do that, in which case using it won't allow this method to work.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I ended up firing ProgressChanged directly from the SqlReader class.

Comment: hi  @svaha can you share your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If `graphData, graphComputations, m_debug` are already members of `ProgressBar` and `worker_DoWork` is a member of `ProgressBar`, then you have nothing more to do. You should be able to access them directly.

Comment: Unfortunately, they are members of Form1. Form1 has my zedgraph (the graph that is being updated). I don't think I can update the graph without those being members of Form1.

Comment: Ok, I understand better now. But you are sending those variables in through your `initialize` function. If you create member variables in `ProgressBar`, then you can just save the references to those values in your initialize function. Then you could just reference them from `worker_DoWork`.

Answer (score 0):

For Rapunzo, above.. My Final Solution was this:

```
Partial Public Class ProgressBar
Dim _mDataAcquisition As New SqliteReader
Public Property DataProgress As Integer = 0
Dim WithEvents _mProgressWorker As New BackgroundWorker
Public Sub Initialize(ByRef graphData As List(Of Channels), ByRef auxData As List(Of Channels), _
                      ByRef graphComputations As List(Of Computations))
    _mDataAcquisition = SqliteReader.GetInstance()
    Show()
    Update()
    _mDataAcquisition.ParseEntireDatabase(graphData, auxData, graphComputations)
    Close()
End Sub
Private Sub ProgressBarStart(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    progress.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks
    _mProgressWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    _mProgressWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    _mProgressWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
    progress.Visible = True
    progress.Maximum = 100
    progress.Value = 0
End Sub
Public Sub WorkerProgressChanged()
    progress.Value = DataProgress
    Invalidate()
End Sub
Private Sub WorkerRunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                     ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) _
                                     Handles _mProgressWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
    progress.Visible = False
    progress.Value = 0
    Close()
End Sub
```

From there, just call ProgressBar.Initialize to start it

To update:

```
    ProgressBar.DataProgress = CInt((currentIt / totalIt) * 100)
    ProgressBar.WorkerProgressChanged()
```

and to end:

```
    ProgressBar.DataProgress = 100
    ProgressBar.WorkerProgressChanged()
```

Hope this helps.